# Is it true that $\operatorname E|X'|^s\le\operatorname E|X|^s$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable such that $\operatorname EX=0$ and $\operatorname E|X|^s<\infty$ with $s>1$. Suppose that $A$ is an event with $p=P(A)>0$ and consider a random variable
$$
X'=XI_{A^c}+p^{-1}\operatorname E[XI_A]I_A,
$$
where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$ and $I_A$ is the indicator of the event $A$.

> Is it true that $\operatorname E|X'|^s\le\operatorname E|X|^s$?

By Hölder's inequality, $\operatorname E|XI_A|\le(\operatorname E|X|^s)^{1/s}p^{1-1/s}$ for $s>1$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
 \operatorname E|X'|^s
 &=\int_{A^c}|X(\omega)|^sdP(\omega)+\int_A|p^{-1}\operatorname E[XI_A]|^sdP(\omega)\\
 &=\operatorname E[|X|^sI_{A^c}]+p^{1-s}|\operatorname E[XI_A]|^s\\
 &\le\operatorname E[|X|^sI_{A^c}]+\operatorname E|X|^s\\
 &\le2\operatorname E|X|^s.
\end{align*}
Hence, I can show that $\operatorname E|X'|^s\le2\operatorname E|X|^s$. But can I drop that $2$ in front of the expected value?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The inequality holds with a factor $1$. To see this, drop the unnecessary hypothesis that $E(X)=0$ and assume without loss of generality that $X\geqslant0$ almost surely. Then, note that it suffices to show that $$E(X1_A)^sp^{1-s}\leqslant E(X^s1_A)\qquad\tag{$\ast$}$$ Now, consider the probability measure $$Q=p^{-1}1_AP$$ Then, $(\ast)$ is equivalent to$$E_Q(X)^s\leqslant E_Q(X^s)$$ which holds, as a simple case of Jensen inequality.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for your comment! I would like to ask for some clarification. (1) We can split $X=X^+-X^-$ and hence we can assume that $X\ge0$ without loss of generality. Is that correct? (2) Do we have that $\operatorname E_Q(X)=\operatorname E(X1_A)p^{1/s-1}$? Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: If you look at the definition of $Q$, you should see that $E_Q(X)=p^{-1}E(X1_A)$.

Comment: @Did Why do we need to assume that $X\ge0$ almost surely? Also, I don't understand the meaning of the expression $Q=p^{-1}1_AP$. Could you please explain how the probability measure $Q$ is defined?

Comment: The measure $Q$ is defined by $$Q(B)=p^{-1}P(A\cap B)=P(B\mid A)$$ for every event $B$. If you are more familiar with the notion, simply note that $$Q=P(\ \mid A)$$